# Do Apps carry XML?(XML file that was created during development)

Tags: android, andengine

I have an Game App, and i'm using a lot of XML's I was wondering if those XML's are carried by the APK? will those XML files will be installed together with the application itself? Because there is a part of my App where I use DOM Parser to update a XML file and the updated XML file will have its content permanently unless you update it again

Comment: where did you put these xmls?

Comment: then of course xmls will be shipped with your apk :)

Comment: oh okay thanks :) btw If I use the directory here in my desktop, is it okay? or should I change the directory to where will the XML will be installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any XML file in the res or asset folder will be shipped with your application inside the APK (be careful though as the XML files in the res folder might get compressed, so be sure to open them using `context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.identifier);`).

As for the second part of your question, any file packed in the APK cannot be modified at runtime. But you can copy the XML files from your app into a folder, either public on the SDCard or in your apps  private directory (for example `context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` ).

Comment: So either way once the app and the XML's are installed I cannot modify it? unless I use the copy, and make that my main XML, and make all the magic happen on that copy of the original XML

Comment: Yes, you cannot modify any data inside the APK, but you can create copies on the device on first use and then rely on those copied files to store data